# How to get iPod/iPhone iOS version from a Mac OS X application?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, applescript

I'm developing a Mac OS X application that uses applescripts to transfer songs to an iPod/iPhone/iPad connected.

I was wondering if there is a way to obtain the iOS version of the iPod/iPhone/iPad connected to the Mac?

I'm using Xcode, so doesn't need to be an applescript code, it can be Objective-C or C or C++.

Comment: 2 questions: Is it connected via USB? Does your application manipulates iTunes to transfer the songs?

Comment: Yes it is connected and Yes it uses iTunes to transfer the songs. I couldn't find any iTunes method or applescript that return me that info. I fount this link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7606975/454165 but I found a workaround to my problem so I stop researching on this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the systemVersion keyword. If you can get the device, you can use

```
[mydevice systemVersion]
```

Comment: Thanks, I gave up on this approach, but it will be helpful, in case you know how, to include here a way to get the device, mostly for other people reading this question in the future.